# How send data to child activity and change status of togglebutton?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I implemented pusher in a parent activity and i receive data in this activity.. I used putextra to create child activity and send data and set the status of togglebutton, but i don't know how change the status of togglebutton when the child activity is open.. Please some snippets, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is not clear enough - the problem is setting the switch or getting the value you sent? Some code could be useful.

Anyway, you should do something like this in your childActivity.onCreate():

```
boolean value  = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("PARAM_NAME", false);
mSwitch.setChecked(value);
```